# Error Box In Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there an error box in Ionic which can be used to display messages/error with the content.

I am not looking for an alert box that pops up.

[Here](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&biw=1920&bih=938&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=p55yWqr0C8vrvgTVqJPwDQ&q=bootstrap%20error%20box&oq=bootstrap%20error%20box&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i24k1.11692.13728.0.13955.10.10.0.0.0.0.195.1416.0j9.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.503...0i13k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.szl34hNAC-A#imgrc=3E1WJc565UygXM:) is an example of what I am looking for.

Personally I think that this should be part of Ionic and not have be implemented using CSS.

Thanks

Comment: no.. you could create a custom component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no existing ionic component specified for errors.
For that, you have to customize it yourself. The error display you've shown in your example is nothing but a text field (`ion-label`) whose class is customized.

Here's an example:
`<ion-label class="label error-label">Error Text</ion-label>`
and then in a different SCSS file you would code for that class.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only way. But a framework like Ionic should offer this out of the box.

Comment: You can try to add that as an issue on their [Github repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues)
But you have to make sure that no similar issue already exists.